# Slide page after page fully loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to slide my page only after it fully loads.
I use

```
 href="page#a"
```

and

```
 href="page#b"
```

however, sections a and b's initial position is not the final position. my page loads charts and data from SPs and it takes a few seconds, making divs a and b go to the lower part of the page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Write your code inside `.load()`

```
$( window ).load(function() {

 //whatever you write here will get executed when the page is fully loaded 

  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend : function() {
       console.log('Before Ajax Request Starts !!');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        /*__YOUR CODE GOES HERE  
        AFTER PAGE LOADS AND AJAX COMPLETES LOADING_
         _____code for sliding ______
        */
    }
  });  



});
```

Comment: Yes, I use highcharts for my charts and I think the page is considered loaded even before the data from the charts are created into a graph

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno :can you tell me where you loading the data ?

Comment: I have a view which contains a partial view. The partial view loads data from both json and sql. The charts' data are populated on javascript by an ajax call on a method from my controller.

Comment: than check the answer update you can do your ajax call inside window `load` and in success you can do the sliding part

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

or

```
$(window).load(function(){ ... });
```